# php compare two associative arrays

Tags: php, compare, associative-array

i have these two `associative arrays`

// the needle array

```
$a = array(
"who" => "you", 
"what" => "thing", 
"where" => "place",
"when" => "hour"
);
```

// the haystack array

```
$b = array(
"when" => "time", 
"where" => "place", 
"who" => "you",
"what" => "thing"
);
```

i want to check if the `$a` has a match with the `b` with it's exact `key` and `value`

and if each key and value from `$a` has an exact match in `$b`.... i want to increment the value of a variable `$c` by 1 and so on...

as we've seen from above there 3 possible match... 
and supposedly results to increment the value of `$c` by 3

`$c = "3";`

i hope some genius can help me...

Comment: In my case the array was multidimensional, I solved the problem comparing the serialize return for each

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### EDIT2

**OP actually used [`array_intersect_assoc()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-assoc.php) for their specific usecase.** (check [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266148/php-compare-two-associative-arrays/10266163?noredirect=1#comment13200932_10266163))

The original answer was not really useful for their case!

---

you can look into the php's [**`array_diff_assoc()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php) function or the [**`array_intersect()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) function.

### *EDIT*

Here's a sample on counting the matched values:

```
<?php
  $a = array(
    "who" => "you", 
    "what" => "thing", 
    "where" => "place",
    "when" => "hour"
  );
  // the haystack array
  $b = array(
    "when" => "time", 
    "where" => "place", 
    "who" => "you",
    "what" => "thing"
  );
  $c = count(array_intersect($a, $b));
  echo $c;
?>
```

[CODEPAD](http://codepad.org/RYo45dBO) link.

Comment: that is not the answer that i'm looking sir.... what i want the most is.... the $c will increment everytime there is an exact match result

Comment: maybe i can use array_intersect_assoc() instead.... and just count the match results...

Comment: i've already found my answer sir... $check_result = count(array_intersect_assoc($a, $b));

Comment: but still thanks.. coz you gave me the idea to use the rray_intersect_assoc() instead....

Comment: @mickmackusa you're right. i updated my answer above w/ relevant information instead.