# How to check two assoc php arrays for equality on values?

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php compare two associative arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266148/php-compare-two-associative-arrays)

I have two PHP arrays

```
$arr1 = array ([0] => apple, [1] => banana);
$arr2 = array ([banana] => banana, [apple] => apple);
```

In my web app, I don't know what would be the order and how many elements would be in these arrays. Moreover, one array uses number  as keys and for the other one, the key = the value.

How can I check that the values of $arr1 equal the values of $arr2 ?

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

Use [array_values](http://php.net/array_values) to extract all the values of both arrays into numerically keyed arrays. Then some sorting/uniqueing to make sure everything's in the same order and an equality test.

Answer (score 1):

Since they have different keys

```
$arr1 = array (0 => "apple", 1 => "banana");
$arr2 = array ("banana" => "banana", "apple" => "apple");
```

You can use `array_diff`

```
if(!array_diff($arr1, $arr2))
{
    // They are the same 
}
```

You can use `array_intersect`

```
if(count($arr1) == count(array_intersect($arr1, $arr2)))
{
      // They are the same ;
}
```

You can use array `array_filter`

```
if(array_filter($arr2,function($var)use($arr1){return !in_array($var,$arr1);}))
{
     // They are the same ;
}
```

You can use `array_values`

```
$arr2 = array_values($arr2);
sort($arr1);sort($arr2); //sort to make sure they are in the same position 

if($arr1 === $arr2)
{
    // They are the same
}
```