# Compare PHP Arrays in Zend

Tags: php, arrays, zend-framework

How can I compare arrays of following format?

```
$arr1 = Array{ "id"=>1, "name"="Tom"}
$arr2 = Array{ "id"=>1, "name"="Tommy"}
```

The result should be false as there is difference.

Comment: You have syntax wrong. Array{ "id"=>1, "name"="Tom"} should be Array{ "id"=>1, "name"=>"Tom"} and check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266148/php-compare-two-associative-arrays

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
array_diff($arr1, $arr2);
```

This will produce an array containing the differences, you could then just check if this array is populated or empty like so:

```
if(empty(array_diff($arr1, $arr2))) {
    // Data is the same
} else {
    // Data is different
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr1 = array("id"=>1, "name"=>"Tommy");
$arr2 = array("id"=>1, "name"=>"Tommy");
$result = array_diff($arr1, $arr2);
if($result==null)
{
return true;
}
else
{
return false;
}
```

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitors, whenn you add some explainaion for your intension